# How to reduce ldap search time?

Tags: ldap

I am going to search one user from a list of 100k entities, but it seems to be taking more than 15 minutes duration and like that I have to search 33000 users,Is there an optimal way which will return results in 5 minutes?

Comment: Show us how you are currently doing it.

Comment: ldap_con.search_s(base_dn,ldap.SCOPE_ONELEVEL,filter) where filter = "(&(objectClass=*)(cn=*))"

Comment: Cant we allow regular expressions in basedn?

Comment: Make sure that `cn` is indexed. Ditto `objectClass`, although that part of this filter is completely pointless and should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange filter. Almost certainly not what you really want.

At  the moment you're looking for any entry of any `objectClass` that even has a `cn` attribute, and presumably you're then searching yourself through the thousands of returned entries for the one you want.

Instead, you should be searching *directly* for the *one* entry you want, by specifying both a concrete `objectClass`, e.g. `inetOrgPerson`, and a concrete `cn`, being the `cn` of the user you're looking for.

You must ensure that both `objectClass` and `cn` are indexed.

Comment: Even we do that, is it possible to make the above search in 5 minutes?

Comment: It will take a couple of seconds, provided you have the indexes I mentioned.

Comment: If cn is indexed, the search should take less than 1/2 second on any modern LDAP implementation.